# Splitting a String with Last Space of Max Characters

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split a String with a Last space of my max allowed character:

**Expectation:**

String name = "John David Guetta MarkHenry Anthoney Sam";

Max Character allowed : **30**

So it should return as:

```
John David Guetta MarkHenry 
Anthoney Sam
```

**Actual Result:**

```
 John David Guetta MarkHenry An
 thoney Sam
```

**Code:**

```
 public static List<String> splitByLength(String str, int n) {
    List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (i > 0 && (i % n == 0)) {
            returnList.add(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(sb.toString())) {
        returnList.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex that accepts up to 30 characters:

```
String name = "John David Guetta MarkHenry Anthoney Sam";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{1,30}(\\s+|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group().trim());
}
```

Note the `(\\s|$)` to break either on a space or once the end of the initial string is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it difficult and troublesome using Regex, so here is a solution that I would use

```
 private static void splitByLength(String str, int n) {
    String newStr = "";
    int splitIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {     
            newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);   //Keep adding chars until you find a space
            if (newStr.length() > n) {   //If newStr's length exceeds 'n', break the loop
                break;
            }
        } else {
            splitIndex = i;    //Store the last space index 
            newStr = newStr + ' ';
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, splitIndex).trim());  //Use the splitIndex to print a substring
    System.out.println(str.substring(splitIndex, str.length()).trim());
}
```